# Autocall function when laravel index function of a controller is called

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance

I have a controller class as follows:

```
class Controller extends BaseController{

protected function function1()
{
    //code
}

protected function function2()
{
     //code
}
}
```

and every controller in the project extends this class such that i can write functions used in multiple controllers in this Controller class.

```
class RandomController extends Controller{

    public function aCertainFunction()
    {
        $this->function1();
        //code 
    {
}
```

I now have a function that should be called every time the index function of any controller is called.
One option is that i manually add this function at the start of every index function in the controllers i have and that i keep doing this for every new controller i create in the future but this doesn't seem efficient to me.

Is there a way to define this function in my Controller class such that every index function in all classes that inherit from this class will automatically call this function?

Comment: Take a read about **Observer Pattern** https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer, then Laravel doc will help you to make it the good way https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at the [Events Listening system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events) embedded in the Laravel framework. Let's admit that you want to trigger `aCertainFunction()` every time `function1` or `function2` is executed.

You'll have to declare an Event class which will be stored into the `namespace App\Events;` (you don't need to extends Controller at all as it is dedicated to another purpose).

The public `handle` function of your Event class will be called to be executed when you trigger the event with the `event()` function. Therefore you will declare your `aCertainFunction` function directly inside your event class (and call it from the `handle` function). Please take a deep look at How Laravel is handling Events as it is really dedicated to delegate and call them on specific purposes (and that's why we call them "listeners").